# calles and handsfree

Tags: android

is there any way to be notified when a person calls or I call or when I removed hand free from socket ? 
I want to make a music player and I need to stop it when a person calls or user removed hand free from socket , how to detect this situation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common method is to listen to the ["BECOMING_NOISY"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY) broadcast intent

Comment: think I have a mediplayer in my main activity , how can I use this ? how can I call stop method ?